# Cannot load image for QLabel background

Tags: qt

my qrc file defined as follows,

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/images">
        <file>Resources/images/background.png</file>
    ....
```

I want to use the file `background.png` as my label's background.
I did like this,

```
label->setStyleSheet( "background-image: url(:/images/background.png);" );
```

but it cannot set the image as background.
Is it anyway to know why label cannot load the image? Cannot find the image?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you want the `/images` prefix for the `Resources/images/background.png` file, so in the resource system the file is available as

```
:/images/Resources/images/background.png
```

If you want *also* to simplify the file's path, use an alias:

```
<file alias="background.png">Resources/images/background.png</file>
```

This will make it available under

```
:/images/background.png
```

For the future, learn how to debug such simple problems yourself: just putting

```
QDirIterator i(":/", QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
while (i.hasNext())
    qDebug() << i.next();
```

in your `main` function will tell you how your resource hierarchy looks like, and so if you're using a wrong resource path.

Comment: well, thanks, I will check it. I found some guys draw UI and use the resource files somewhere. it's easy for one guy work with CSS mixed with C++, and waste time on teamwork.